# how can I find a certain file within a folder and replace it using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

how can I find a certain file within a folder and replace it using a batch file?

for instance you provide the path for the folder and it looks through the folder and responds
with the path for the file name given

Comment: Preferably in batch because what I want to do once it finds the path is to replace the file with a different file using that path

Comment: Please use the search facility at the top of the page to locate already existing code you can adapt as needed. Your post shows absolutely no effort on your part, please take the [tour] and read through the linked content within [ask], to guide you how to get the best from StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can just use 'where' or 'whereis' unix/shell command then you'll have the short path.

```
whereis initialFile.txt
-> /etc/Folder/initialFile.txt

echo 'Hello, World!' > /etc/Folder/initialFile.txt
```

And you can see result like this:

```
cat /etc/Folder/initialFile.txt
```

(Add 'realpath' command on the short path, and you'll get the real path.)